# What is the ruby equivalent of #define A B in C/C++?

Tags: ruby

Is there any Ruby equivalent of C/C++ macro?

```
#define something somethingelse
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on why you would need one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby projects typically have neither a pre-processing nor a compilation step and usage of any pre-processor is not common.

You can [define constants](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_constants.html) by using capitalized variable names.

However, if you really need a pre-processor then you can use [CPP](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) with ruby or any other language - it does not really care about the actual syntax.

Comment: The only correct answer here so far. Also, `s/upper case/capitalized/`.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer. Nevertheless, upper case is the convention for constants (except classes and modules).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct equivalent, but you can do it. For example,

```
#DEFINE PI 3.14159
```

in the C/C++ Preprocessor can be

```
PI=3.14159
```

in ruby. Capitalized variables are constants in ruby.

The other type of macro being, for example

```
#DEFINE ADD(A, B) A + B
```

is

```
def add(a, b)
  a + b
end
```

in ruby. There is real reason to use a C/C++ style macro in ruby when it comes to function macros as you can easily define methods in ruby that work just as well as C/C++ style macros.

Comment: If you [erroneously] decided that Ruby constant is an equivalent of C/C++ preprocessor macro, `#define ADD(A, B) A + B` would be `ADD = ->(a, b) { a + b }`.

Comment: Why would you define a preprocessor macro as a lambda instead of a method? `ADD.call(1,2)` is much less C like than `add(1, 2)`.

Comment: If you want for `ADD` to not be overriden I guess that could work, but that's unlikely to be a concern. I was more equating C's macro-style _symbolic constants_ to ruby's constants.

Comment: FYI: Ruby constants are perfectly overwritable.

Comment: @mudasobwa Yes, but reassigning a constant gives a warning.

Comment: Not at all, if one starts with [`Module#remove_const`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-remove_const).

Comment: Yes, but `A = 5` then `A = 4` will give `Warning: already initialized constant A`.